# How to Pass Css Class as in Array Object?

Tags: angular, typescript

How `Css` class can be passed as an array object in .ts file and get bound in 
the component.html file.[See in the image className,I want component.`css`

create class bind with this and use in component.html like {{item.className}}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUEVq.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** not as images nor offsite resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do archive this by **[ngClass]** here is the example

```
<div *ngFor="let data of ArrayObj; let i = index">
   <div [ngClass]="data.className">
   </div>
</div>
```